# jQuery Animation : How to move along an assigned arc / beizer curve?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I checked [jQuery Path plugin](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path), and tried to animate a DIV following along a path. I succeed to make the DIV moving along the path, but I would like the DIV to head according to the path direction ( rotate when following the beizer path ). How can I do it?

Here is my current code :

```
$('#car001').click(function() {
    var bezier_params = {
        start: { 
          x: 185, 
          y: 385, 
          angle: 50
        },  
        end: { 
          x:540,
          y:110, 
          angle: -10, 
          length: 0.25
        }
      }
      $("#car001").animate({path : new $.path.bezier(bezier_params)}, 1000);
});
```

which `$('#car001')` contains 1 image only.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jquery.path should be doing it with [its call to `atan2`](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path/blob/master/jquery.path.js#L109).

You might be better served if you switched to https://github.com/heygrady/curve, which also has [a blog post with working jsfiddle demos](http://heygrady.com/blog/2011/07/20/animating-with-curves-in-jquery/).

I'm sure there are many other alternatives. If you're not tied to the HTML DOM, you can also try one of [the many SVG libraries out there](http://codepen.io/mattsince87/details/snqLy).